# SQL "in" statement

Tags: mysql, sql

DB is  MySQL. There is one table which structure is showed below:

```
select * from table1
id column1
-- --------
1  3,4,5
2  3,7,8
```

And sql which is not working correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 3 in (column1)
```

I know that the structure of the table is not right. But it was done before me. What can you suggest me in this way? or something that will perform the meaning of this sql? Thanks.

Comment: Use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function. But only until you normalize your table.

Comment: Storing comma separated values in db columns is never good: [Is it that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: what you want to fetch from query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please normalize your table. Read why [storing comma separated values in a db column is really bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

If you are not allowed to, use **[`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, column1)
```

Comment: I know that it is bad. This structure was created before me and by normalizing the table we have to change a lot of sql statements in application. Thank you, ypercube. And one more question please :) Is FIND_IN_SET() better than using LIKE '%,3,%'(ofcourse after adding commas to the beginning end to the end)? Because there will be over 500.000 records in this table.

Comment: With 500K rows, both will be slow. You'll have to test but I think `FIND_IN_SET()` will be faster than `CONCAT`+`LIKE` or `LIKE OR LIKE` solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE "%,3,%" OR column1 LIKE "3,%" OR column1 LIKE "%,3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_in_set` It Returns position of value in string of comma-separated values

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, column1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IN is a operator that you use to compare whether the left operand is in one of the values returned by a single column subquery If you want to use IN  you would have to use WHERE 3,4,5 IN (column1)